# Go to route in helper specs in RSpec does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an "Add friend" button in user profile pages (users#show) and I want to test that the button does not show up on your own profile page (current_user's)

I have this in the view file (users/show.html.haml):

```
- unless current_user == params[:id]
  = button_to 'Add friend', path
```

I want to create a helper for it in `UsersHelper`:

```
module UsersHelper
  def correct_user
    current_user == params[:id]
  end
end
```

So in the view it would be:

```
- unless correct_user
  = button_to 'Add friend', path
```

**How do I test this in RSpec?**

In my `spec/helpers/users_helper_spec.rb` file I have:

```
it 'checks correct user' do
  sign_in( user = create(:user) )
  user2 = create(:user, name: 'foobar')
  get :show, params: { id: user2.to_param }
  expect(helper.correct_user).to be true
end
```

I have this for the `sign_in` (current_user) Devise helper that signs in the user:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :helper
end
```

Basically the test fails because doing `get :show, params: { id: user2.to_param }` is giving me an error and gives me the impression that routing is not possible in helper specs.

How do I go about testing `correct_user` helper? Should I just move it to the controller (so I can do `get :show, params: { id: user2.to_param }` in the spec) and test it there? (and just make it a helper method `helper_method :correct_user`)

Comment: This `current_user == params[:id]` will always evaluate to `false`, because `current_user` will be an object and `params[:id]` will id of an object.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh Yes I wasn't looking at my code when I wrote the question. It's actually `current_user.to_param == params[:id]`. But you are right in your answer below that I should just use the user object (`@user`) to compare to the current user. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be using `params[:id]` to check if `user` matches `current_user`. You must have fetched the `User` with `params[:id]` in your controller action. Say, you stored it in a variable `@user`. Then, you can modify your helper and view like this:

Helper:

```
module UsersHelper
  def can_add_friend?(user)
    current_user != user
  end
end
```

View:

```
- if can_add_friend?(@user)
  = button_to 'Add friend', path
```

It would be easier to write rspec for this helper method now.

```
it 'checks correct user' do
  sign_in( user = create(:user) )
  user2 = create(:user, name: 'foobar')
  expect(helper.can_add_friend?(user2)).to be true
  expect(helper.can_add_friend?(user)).to be false
end
```

Comment: This is great! As it's almost a pre-requisite to have `@user = User.find(params[:id])` in the show action (users#show). Thanks!

Comment: BTW, any reason why one should not use params to check with the current_user? I know in some cases it's because if I change the routes to not include user ids. But what would be the other reasons?

Comment: I just think its neat to use params in controller only. Yes, the reason could be you mentioned above. You may access the same view file in other routes, where you won't be sending `:id` in params.